# jQuery : toggle class opening all class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code and I have gone through many SO question but still I am not able to make it run.

I want to use `toggle` but **problem** is that It is opening all the class related to this.What I want is to **toggle only class that is clicked**.

I have tried `e.preventDefault` , `e.stopPropagation();` and `return false`.But none of them worked for me.

**NOTE** I don't know the use of above mentioned three.I have used them at the **end** not at the beginning.

```js
$(".read").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        $(".expand").toggle();
  return false;
    });
```

```css
.expand{display:none;background:#000;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem that `$(".expand")` returns all elements that has class `.expand`, but you need get only one element. You can do it like this

```
$(".read").click(function(e){
  $(this).next('.expand').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/marale/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".read").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next(".expand").toggle();
  return false;
    });
```

```css
.expand{display:none;background:#000;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$(".read").click(function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    $(".read").next(".expand").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following code:

```js
$(".read").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.expand').toggle();
  return false;
    });
```

```css
.expand{display:none;background:#000;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Here next() simply grabs the next element and $(this) referrs to the one currently clicked on.

```js
$(".read").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().toggleClass('expand');
  return false;
    });
```

```css
.expand{display:none;background:#000;color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Text</p>
<div class="read">Read More</div>
<div class="expand">Lorem Ipsum text again !</div>
```